# iOS - SymbolSet Font Icons not working

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, icons, symbols

1. I purchased the font icon bundle from https://symbolset.com
2. I copied the ss-social-regular.tff into the project.
3. In info.plist, I added ss-social-regular.tff under Font provided by application.
4. In my view controller, I created a UILabel in code, set the font as "ss-social-regular", and set the text as @"\uF610". (this is the Facebook icon. i got U+F610 by hovering over the icon in Font Book)
5. The result is a box with a question mark inside.

I've tried many different variations for the string set to label text, but none have worked.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: No, I asked the designer to provide me with .png files instead